# Gym not registering Brakeout environment

Tags: python, openai-gym

I want to use OpenAI gym environment 'ALE/Breakout-v5'

I try to access it with

```
import gym
env = gym.make("ALE/Breakout-v5")
```

but I get the following error:

```
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 158, in spec
    def _check_name_exists(ns: Optional[str], name: str):
KeyError: 'ALE/Breakout-v5'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/breakoutAI/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    env = gym.make("ALE/Breakout-v5")
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 235, in make
    version_list_msg = ", ".join(f"`v{spec_.version}`" for spec_ in env_specs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 128, in make
    # Initialize namespace, name, version
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 203, in spec
    VersionNotFound: The ``version`` used doesn't exist
gym.error.UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: ALE/Breakout-v5
```

I use gym version 0.21.0 but I tried latest one and 0.20.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [ale-py](https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment)?
`pip install ale-py`

Comment: yeah I did, thanks for trying tho